# How to install a C# Windows Service on a remote server?

Tags: c#, windows-services

Hi I have developed a C# Windows Service in Visual Studio.
I am able to install this service on my local machine and it works fine.
Now I want to be able to **install it on a remote server**.

**Can you tell me how to do this?**

My service is just built on the **Windows Service VS template, so it's all very simple**.

**I am not so geeky, so it would be useful with some tutorial, manual which I can understand.**

I am running VS 2010 Professional.

Comment: Why can't you do it the same way as you did on your local machine?

Comment: What's the difference between installing it locally and installing it on a remote server?

Comment: Currently I am installing on my local machine with VS External Tools
Command: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
Arguments: MyService.exe
Initial directory: $(ProjectDir)/bin/debug
Can I install on a remote server from VS 2010 Professional?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to have Remote Desktop access to the server.

When you are in you can do it via the commandline using something like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil /LogToConsole=true C:\Path\To\Service.exe
```

Then you can manage it (start it, set it to auto start, stop it, restart it) by going to Start | Run and typing

```
services.msc
```

then press enter.

To uninstall it use:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil /u /LogToConsole=true C:\Path\To\Service.exe
```

But you will need to have stopped the service first.

Note: There is probably a new util in newer .net releases - my notes are from a while ago when I built a 2.0 service. Look in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` for a version number that matches the .net you're developing in.

Comment: I have Remote Desktop to the server, is all I need to bring to the remote server MyService.exe? What about when I later need to change the configuration? I have some application settings in my service. Will some configuration files be created during the install process?

Comment: Thank you all for your assistence, I had Remote Desktop, so I just copy-pasted the files to the Remote Desktop and did something like above. http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/how-to-install-windows-service-using.html

Comment: What if myservice.exe makes use of third-party library DLLs?  What is the best way to install them on the remote server?

Answer (score 9):

Use the [SC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) command.

```
sc \\remotecomputer create newservice binpath= C:\Windows\System32\Newserv.exe 
   start= auto obj= DOMAIN\username password= pwd
```

Comment: I try to paste a command into the command prompt of SC.EXE, but when I do it, it just disappears and I don't know what is happening, the command prompt just disappears :(

Comment: @RuneHansen Have you found it?

Comment: are you doing this in powershell ,  if so you need to specify sc.exe  as set-content uses sc as an alias